# C# Form Application not closing the panel's User control

Tags: c#, .net, forms, panel

I have created one main form(MainImagincup) with two panels(panel,panel2).
And an usercontrol to show in the panel2.
I have used this code to show :

Number_Eng_Ban jk = new Number_Eng_Ban();

```
        jk.Show();
        panel2.Controls.Add(jk);
```

And this code to remove:

```
            MainImaginCp pk = new MainImaginCp();
            Number_Eng_Ban jk = new Number_Eng_Ban();
            pk.panel2.Controls.Clear();
            pk.panel2.Controls.Remove(jk);
```

But it is not removing from the main form . What I can do ?

Answer (score 1):

jk is well-referenced when you call `pk.panel2.Controls.Remove(jk);`?
It seems to me that jk is cleared when you exit method in which you add it to the panel.
You should try to declare `Number_Eng_Ban jk;` in your class, then (when you want to add it) do `jk = new Number_Eng_Ban();`

Comment: It is not resolving my problem .. I tried but failed .. the same problem arises ..

Comment: @Prodip: post your new code and I'll try it tomorrow morning (it's evening now and my children need me). I wanna think we're going to solve your problem soon :)

Comment: I am using two different forms one as mainform and another as usercontrol and I want to show and clear the usercontrol from the panel of main form. I have made your suggesion but no result ..   The usercontrol is showing but not removing from the panel of another form and my exit button is on the usercontrol form.    
        {
            MainImaginCp pk = new MainImaginCp();
            Number_Eng_Ban jk;
            jk = new Number_Eng_Ban();
            pk.panel2.Controls.Clear();
            pk.panel2.Controls.Remove(jk);
           
        }

Comment: @Prodip: post your code (important parts), both mainform and usercontrol.